# In MVC parlance, how do you "notify" a grandparent component of a model's change?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

There are a lot of examples about how to setup a JTable and its associated model, but I'm wondering how to go about letting a the JFrame "controller" know that a JTable's model is completely loaded.

Do I just delegate up to the grandparents? Should I be employing an observer pattern? Or am I modifying the model in the wrong place? Should the model be controlled by the JTable controller?